# sort array of objects in javascript and save result in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

my javascript object array is just like that...

```
$scope.object[]={name:azhar, rating:4},
                 {name:raheel, rating:1},  
                 {name:faran, rating:5}
```

i'm getting output like that in console if i print my array of objects

```
0:
  Rating:"4.00"
  name:"Azhar"
1:
  Rating:"1.00"
  name:"raheel"
2:
  Rating:"5.00"
  name:"faran"
```

in java script, i'm sending data like this in my array.

```
$scope.object[$scope.arraycount]={name:$scope.array[$scope.arraycount],Rating:$scope.avgRating}
```

i want to sort this array in java script can anyone help me?

Comment: sort on basis of which property ?

Comment: search SO for an answer are a lot of questions similar to this one

Comment: @rahul on the basis of rating

Comment: @edwin tried all combinations but all in vain

Comment: Try this `$scope.object.sort((a,b) => a.rating - b.rating);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
let data = [{name:"azhar", rating:4},
                 {name:"raheel", rating:1},  
                 {name:"faran", rating:5}];
                 
data.sort((a,b) => b.rating - a.rating);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: what if i want to sort reverse order like 5 ,4,3,2,1

Comment: @AzharCh just do the opposite :P updated